# How to insert DATE into AZURE SQL DATABASE with PHP and AZURE SQL CONSOLE

Tags: php, sql, azure

**PROBLEM**

Recently, I have created the table with PHP and it worked.

```
$woQuery = "CREATE TABLE WOQUERY (
            nameNO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
            commissionDate DATE,  
            serviceType TEXT NOT NULL, 
            serviceNo TEXT NOT NULL,
            userNameC CHAR(30), 
            dateAssigned DATE);
```

However, when I tried to insert date

```
/* Proceeds with the upload */
        $sql = "INSERT INTO WOQUERY VALUES（?,?,?,?);";

        /* array(nameWO, commissionDate , serviceType, serviceNo) */
        $params = array($extractor[0], $extractor[1], $extractor[2], $extractor[3]);


        if (!sqlsrv_query($databaseController, $sql, $params)) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            return false;
        } else {
            print("Successfully uploaded");
            return true;
        }
```

My program kept stopping at die. Saying that Incorrect syntax. Tho I went around stackoverflow to look for similar problem none of them solved my issue.

This led me to go into Microsoft AZURE SQL's console to test out.

```
INSERT INTO WOQUERY ('xadsada', '28/01/2019', 'helpService', '12345', 'johnny' , '03/02/2019');
```

Despite trying to use FORMAT() or CAST() or just leaving it as '28/01/2019'.

I will get errors like "Conversion failed when converting date/time from string" or "string or binary data would be truncated".

**HELP**

I was wondering if there is any way for me to insert the date into AZURE SQL (**not** msssql/sqlite/mysql)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to insert date is if you follow 'mm-dd-yyyy' format and not 'dd-mm-yyyy'. Hence the only way I can think of now is to change my column datatype to string and store the date.

If I ever need the date I will get the date from SQL and then convert it into date format.

Comment: its the same answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

Your values are not matching with the types of columns, however query looks correct. You need to send a value of data type **DATE** for the date columns or change it to String type or send **`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`**

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrote wrong insert string. You did not declare columns name before declare values.
example insert string:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

View document in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: still the same problem